# Trying to clone old linux machines using to img methods

Tags: linux, backup, clone, veeam

I found this handy website to show how to clone drives to a img file:

https://www.maketecheasier.com/clone-entire-hard-drive-linux/

What neatish looking option was partimage, so I wanted to get that rolling on our very old, very not updated systems (updating would break the very old scientific hardware they have on them).

```
sudo yum install partimage
Loaded plugins: kernel-module
http://ftp.scientificlinux.org/linux/scientific/54/i386/SL/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404: Not Found
Trying other mirror.
http://ftp1.scientificlinux.org/linux/scientific/54/i386/SL/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404: Not Found
Trying other mirror.
http://ftp2.scientificlinux.org/linux/scientific/54/i386/SL/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404: Not Found
Trying other mirror.
ftp://ftp.scientificlinux.org/linux/scientific/54/i386/SL/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 4] IOError: [Errno ftp error] 550 Failed to change directory.
Trying other mirror.
http://ftp.scientificlinux.org/linux/scientific/54/i386/updates/security/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404: Not Found
Trying other mirror.
http://ftp1.scientificlinux.org/linux/scientific/54/i386/updates/security/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404: Not Found
Trying other mirror.
http://ftp2.scientificlinux.org/linux/scientific/54/i386/updates/security/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404: Not Found
Trying other mirror.
ftp://ftp.scientificlinux.org/linux/scientific/54/i386/updates/security/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 4] IOError: [Errno ftp error] 550 Failed to change directory.
Trying other mirror.
Setting up Install Process
No package partimage available.
Nothing to do
```

The version of linux is:

```
cat /etc/*-release
Scientific Linux SL release 5.4 (Boron)

uname -r
2.6.18-164.15.1.el5PAE
```

Am I just out of luck for doing it this way?  Which way is a good way for backing up these system.  We use Veeam but for these old machine they are sooo not supported and I cannot get their agents on it.

Best I had was to use what was suggested here

https://evpo.net/wiki/backup-and-restore-your-linux-system-disk.html

and basically gzip the os.  I don't know if this works and I really don't ever want to find out.

The partimage option looks nice to make a clone of the drive without having physically add a drive to clone.   I just again cannot seem to get it even installed.

Comment: When you can't run whatever tools you need in your legacy OS to me a solution would be to boot a LiveImage / rescue image from CD or a  thumb drive. Then you can run your image cloning tasks in a more recent runtime environment.

Comment: This is a pretty good option.  I was hoping there was something that could be done whilst the OS is running.  So far I just tarballed using mnt bind the OS and also /etc/ and home folders of every machine.  Mostly because no one wants to take these machines off line :/